# изменение картинки по клику src

Tags: javascript

При изменение картинки по src, она меняется, но при повторном клике на исходную не возвращается. Помогите разобраться.

Ссылка https://jsbin.com/fulehihavi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Что конкретно вам не понятно?

Comment: Не понятно почему при повторном клике исходная картинка не возвращается

Answer (score 0):

```
if (img.src == "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2018-06/1528641301_5.jpg") {// было одно равно
```